# Sending JTable data from Server to Client JTable through sockets

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, jtable, chat

I have a JTable on my SERVER form, it is populated from MySQL database, coded in constructor:

```
String sql = "SELECT * from fiekorari";
        try{
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        res=pst.executeQuery();
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(res));
        pst.close();
        res.close();
        } catch (SQLException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Connection is Established on main using TCP connection, SERVER SIDE:

```
public class Serveri extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    static ServerSocket ss;
    static Socket s;
    static DataInputStream din;
    static DataOutputStream dout;
    private JTextField txtMesazhi;
    private static JTextArea txtA;
    static Connection conn=null;
    static ResultSet res= null;
    static PreparedStatement pst = null;
    private Object id;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Serveri frame = new Serveri();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        SqlConn.getConnection();
        String msgin="";
        try 
        {
            ss=new ServerSocket(1201);
            s=ss.accept();
            din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()); //code continues with chat programming
```

I want to send data from JTable of Server side to JTable of Client Side, im not sure if this is the right approach to it, but my assignment is that so server will read DB data and it sends it to the client.

Below is the code of Client side which establishes a connection through TCP for chatting, but now ill have to add a table which reads data from Servers table through sockets:

```
public class Klienti extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtMesazhi;
    private static JTextArea txtShfaq1;
    static Socket s;
    static DataInputStream din;
    static DataOutputStream dout;
    private JButton btnNewButton;
    public static String sql1;
    private JTable table;
    private JTextField txtEmri;
    private JTextField txtMbiemri;
    private JTextField txtOra;
    static Connection conn=null;
    static ResultSet res= null;
    static PreparedStatement pst = null;
     private Pattern pattern;
     private Matcher matcher;
     private String loc;



    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Klienti frame = new Klienti();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        //SqlConn.getConnection();
        try 
        {
            s=new Socket("localhost",1201);
            din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

//code in constructor Client side which sends text message to Server through sockets: 

dout.writeUTF(msgout);
            txtShfaq1.setText(txtShfaq1.getText().trim()+"\nJu:\t"+msgout);
            txt.setText("");
```

Answer (score 0):

No you should not send JTable from server to client.
Actually server should not have any swing component.
It should just fetch data on request and send just the data in a suitable format, not wrapped in a JTable.

Another point, as far as possible do not do plain socket communication.
Use higher level protocol like HTTP. Server can run a http web service and can make data available in json,xml format.

Client can use any of the many available http clients to get data from the server. These libraries have taken care of many of the socket connection issues.